# Discontinuity of $f(x,y)=1$ if $x$ or $y$ is rational, $0$ else

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $y\in\mathbb{Q}$

$f(x,y)=0$ else

This looks like the Dirichlet-function in $\mathbb{R}$, does that mean you prove discontinuity  in basically the same way?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove discontinuity?

Comment: It's just about the same, yes: in fact I believe you can make the discontinuity of this function follow completely from the discontinuity of the Dirichlet function.

Comment: If $\Delta: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is the diagonal mapping ($\Delta(x) = (x, x)$), then $f \circ \Delta$ is the Dirichlet function, which you know is not continuous, but $\Delta$ is continuous, so what can you conclude about the continuity of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Every rational can be the limit of an irrational sequence and vice versa! That is all you need! eg take (0,0) and consider $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\to 0$.Then we get a sequence of zeros tending to 1, which is a contradiction. I leave the other cases to you.